# App for Windows 8 pro

Tags: windows-8, cordova

I need to create an application that runs on windows 8 pro.

When building my application with phonegap I get a resulting .xap file for Windows8 phone.
This can't be executed so I assume I need a .exe.
I also read about .appx files.

Can anyone clearify the difference between all the extensions and what my options are for a windows 8 PRO - application. Is it possible to use phonegap or is this only for windows phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 are different platforms with some common roots.  XAP is the deployment vehicle for phone, and .appx is for Windows 8.

Since PhoneGap is just a JavaScript library, it can be used with Windows 8 applications, but you'll need to incorporate it into a Windows 8 HTML5/JavaScript application.  Here's a blog post that should get you on your way: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/glengordon/archive/2012/08/06/windows-8-apps-for-the-phonegap-developer.aspx